# How can I keep on-the-fly application-level statistics in an application running under Apache?

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, pylons, fork

I have an application running under apache that I want to keep "in the moment" statistics on.  I want to have the application tell me things like:

- requests per second, broken down by types of request
- latency to make requests to various backend services via thrift (broken down by service and server)
- number of errors being served per second
- etc.

I want to do this without any external dependencies.  However, I'm running into issues sharing statistics between apache processes.  Obviously, I can't just use global memory.  What is a good pattern for this sort of issue?

The application is written in python using pylons, though I suspect this is more of a "communication across processes" design question than something that's python specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could keep the relevant counters and other statistics in a memcached, that is accessed by all apache processes?

Comment: Yeah, that's a thought, but as I mentioned above, I'd really like this to work without any external dependencies, since it will be used for diagnosing problems when other services might not be working properly.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do this without any external
>   dependencies.

**What if your apache dies somehow?** (Separation of concerns?)

Personally I am using (redundant) [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) to monitor the hardware itself, services, **and application metrics**. This way i can easily/automatically plot "requests per second/users online", "cpu load/user activy X per second" etc. graphs which help with lots of things.

Writing plugins for nagios is really easy, also there are thousands of premade scripts in any language.

**Apache monitoring**

I am monitoring apache by extracting the information I need from the apache mod_status page via nagios plugin.

Example plugin response:

`APACHE OK - 0.080 sec. response time, Busy/Idle 18/16, open 766/800, ReqPerSec 12.4, BytesPerReq 3074, BytesPerSec 38034`

**Application Monitoring**

I used mod_status just as an example for your list of things you'd like to monitor.

For our application we have a very small framework for Nagios plugins, so basically every nagios check is a small class which runs its check against a cache or database and returns its value to nagios (small and simple commandline-script).

more examples:

```
Memcache:
OK - consumption: 82.88% (106.1 MBytes/128.0 MBytes), connections: 2, requests/s: 10.99, hitrate: 95.2% (34601210/36346999), getrate: 50.1% (36346999/72542987)

Application feature #1 usage:
OK - last 5m: 22 last 24h: 655 ever: 26121

Application feature #2 usage:
OK - last 5m: 39 last 24h: 11011

Other applications metrics:
OK - users online: 556
```

What I want to say: Extending Nagios for application monitoring is very easy.
With my little framework which took me 3-4 hours to write, any check I am adding takes me just some minutes now.

[Nagios plug-in development guidelines](http://nagiosplug.sourceforge.net/developer-guidelines.html)

Comment: We are using nagios.  However, we want to gather application level statistics that go beyond what mod_status can provide.  Perhaps a good way to rephrase the question would be "How do I create something like mod_status with custom application statistics?"

Comment: Edited my answer for more application monitoring details

Answer (score -1):

Use pylons.g object. It is an instance of Globals class in your Pylons application's lib/app_globals.py file. Its state changes will be visible to all threads, so stuff in it needs to be threadsafe.

lib/app_globals.py:

```
class Globals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.requests_served = 0
```

controllers/status.py:

```
from pylons import g

class StatusController(BaseController):
    def status(self):
        g.requests_served += 1
        return "Served %d requests." % g.requests_served
```

Comment: This doesn't work across different processes (which happens with both prefork and workers models).  This is the obvious approach, and one we've already tried:)